# Will I need to use glTexImage if OpenGL 4.2 is unavailable?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I'm rewriting my rendering library, and greatly enjoy how `glTexStorage2D()` works, as well as `glBufferStorage()`.  They're wonderful, allocating the space and defining the object in an immutable way, which works very well with the interface I designed.

However, I just learned it is an OpenGL 4.2 feature.  I'm targeting OpenGL 3.3 (I think?) but hoping for a way to avoid `glTexImage2D()` which uses mutable storage that has proven difficult to use safely.

Also... I'm *gravely* unfamiliar with how OpenGL's version system works, or what it even means to "target" one version over the other...

Is it as simple as just, this functionality is unavailable to me below 4.2 and that's that?  Or are there alternative functions I could use?  Or if I attempt to just create a 4.5 OpenGL context (the latest version I know of), would the OpenGL driver be required to emulate any features it doesn't have access to on the GPU?  Or is that not even remotely how any of that works?  I have very little knowledge about it, so maybe this all sounds foolish.

I just really like some of the newer OpenGL 4.x features like immutable storage and tessellation shaders, but don't want to exclude too many people from running my programs.  Would I have to implement an alternative texture allocation method using `glTexImage()` if a platform isn't capable of running OpenGL 4.2?

Comment: [`glTexStorage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexStorage2D.xhtml) is available since OpenGL 4.2. [`glBufferStorage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferStorage.xhtml) is available since OpenGL 4.4. You can find OpenGL specifications here: [OpenGL specification - Khronos OpenGL registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php).

Comment: *"Is it as simple as just, this functionality is unavailable to me below 4.2 a"* - Yes  it is. However, OpenGL features may be available in earlier versions through extensions. However, this depends on the hardware and the driver.

Comment: Ah, I should be thankful it's as simple as that, at least.  Embarrassing to ask such a huge question that boiled to "can I use opengl 4 from opengl 3" aha, but thank you.

Comment: There are good chances that older hardware that cannot implement OpenGL 4+ (e.g. lacks tessellation on the GPU), still can implement `glTexStorage` in the driver. If it does, it will expose that functionality through the [ARB_texture_storage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_texture_storage.txt) extension. Similarly [ARB_buffer_storage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_buffer_storage.txt) for the other one. These extensions are over **ten** (eight) years old at this point.